# Unicode character display in emacs info under Chromebook secure shell

Tags: terminal-emacs, ssh, unicode

This may not be an Emacs configuration issue, but here are the symptoms:

- On a Chromebook, I'm using chrome's Secure Shell Extension v0.18 to
- ssh in to an Ubuntu 16.04 host, `LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8`, and
- Run Emacs 24.5.1 in the terminal via `emacs -nw`, and
- Pull up the Gnu Calc info documentation, and search for `calc-exp`

It displays `\u` entities in the `*info*` buffer (below), which are all Unicode left/right single quotes.  However, I couldn't find anything in searches, and viewing the info file directly using `less` showed the characters in angle brackets and hex digits.

I'd appreciate it if someone could even just note if/where they can see `*info*` come up similarly, maybe using a different ssh client or Emacs/Ubuntu version.

Verbatim from `*info*` buffer:

```
The \u2018B\u2019 (\u2018calc-log\u2019) [\u2018log\u2019] command computes a logarithm to any
base.  For example, \u20181024 <RET> 2 B\u2019 produces 10, since \u20182^10 = 1024\u2019.
```

Verbatim from `less`:

```
The <E2><80><98>B<E2><80><99> (<E2><80><98>calc-log<E2><80><99>) [<E2><80><98>log<E2><80><99>] command computes a logarithm to any
base.  For example, <E2><80><98>1024 <RET> 2 B<E2><80><99> produces 10, since <E2><80><98>2^10 = 1024<E2><80><99>.
```